# SOLR: How to boost the result with multiple values with edismax?

Tags: solr

I have this type of data in solr.

```
{
    "MerchantId":"1",
    "Name":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 10",
},
{
    "MerchantId":"1",
    "Name":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 12",
},
{
    "MerchantId":"2",
    "Name":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 10",
},
{
    "MerchantId":"2",
    "Name":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 12",
},
{
    "MerchantId":"3",
    "Name":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 10",
},
{
    "MerchantId":"3",
    "Name":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 12",
},
{
    "MerchantId":"4",
    "Name":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 10",
},
{
    "MerchantId":"4",
    "Name":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 12",
},
```

Now I want to boost the result by **MerchantId** so I used the below Query

```
"params":{
      "q":"Name:black+top",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "_":"1590574183676",
      "bq":"MerchantId:2^10"}
},
```

This query works as expected. But how to boost 2 or more **MerchantId**?

Also there is **Boost** parameter available for **eDismax** so how to use this parameter and what are the available values for this?

Can we use **Boost** paramter to boost by **MerchantId**?

Comment: can you try like MerchantId:2^10 OR MerchantId:4^8...

Comment: I tried this but If I want to display merchant 4 on top and then Merchant 2, this is not working in this case

Comment: Apply a larger boost til MerchantId:4 - `bq=MerchantId:4^100 MerchantId:2^10`. The difference between `boost` and `bq` is that one is additive, the other is multiplicative. Usually `boost` gives you a better result.

Comment: ok so how to use boost for this query?

Comment: qf=MerchantId:4^10 MerchantId:2^2

Comment: Usually boost gives you a better result.>>> do you know how to use Boost parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/TestDemo4/select?bq=MerchantId:2^10%20OR%20MerchantId:4^5%20OR%20MerchantId:3^3&defType=edismax&q=MerchantName:black%20top
```

Here is how the response will look like:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"MerchantName:black top",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "bq":"MerchantId:2^10 OR MerchantId:4^5 OR MerchantId:3^3"}},
  "response":{"numFound":8,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "MerchantId":"2",
        "MerchantName":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 10",
        "id":"a4480fda-4290-465b-9df2-0b1a1ff85dc8",
        "_version_":1667935688585117696},
      {
        "MerchantId":"2",
        "MerchantName":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 12",
        "id":"1c1c76b6-5db7-4175-bec9-48b19b01dfcb",
        "_version_":1667935688585117697},
      {
        "MerchantId":"4",
        "MerchantName":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 10",
        "id":"6c8f9180-0d73-4e1e-9f03-d2d7c4f936d6",
        "_version_":1667935688586166273},
      {
        "MerchantId":"4",
        "MerchantName":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 12",
        "id":"ea076d75-9ce7-4266-a110-ed78ac132e42",
        "_version_":1667935688587214848},
      {
        "MerchantId":"3",
        "MerchantName":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 10",
        "id":"d99345d0-021f-4a29-bb94-57f2f6c00426",
        "_version_":1667935688585117698},
      {
        "MerchantId":"3",
        "MerchantName":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 12",
        "id":"23fe84a4-b918-4836-a01d-677d62e1ff42",
        "_version_":1667935688586166272},
      {
        "MerchantId":"1",
        "MerchantName":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 10",
        "id":"ecb42a06-b989-4cfe-aca4-bf5b5307857a",
        "_version_":1667935688583020544},
      {
        "MerchantId":"1",
        "MerchantName":"8055 Lace Top, Black / 12",
        "id":"3025c18e-a839-49bc-917c-280c29dd8604",
        "_version_":1667935688584069120}]
  }
```